# How to tell C++ to use a different function (with the same name as another function)?

Tags: c++

I have two libraries included in my program which both have the same function name, but I need to be able to use both, but I also need C++ to know which one I'm referring to (in certain places I will only be referring to one or the other). The reason why I'm doing this is because I am making my own library and I want to have certain names for my functions, but they are conflicting with functions in someone else's library that I've included, and to make matters worse, some of my functions in my library actually USE the functions in the other persons library which has the same name.

My library is just a .h/.cpp file by the way. Also, when calling MY functions, I don't want any extra luggage such as myNameSpace::myFunc(). I just want to call it myFunc(). However, I don't mind calling the other persons function using a namespace (though I don't want to modify their library in case I break something). (I'm completely new to C++ btw)

HERES MY NEW (TEST - SO FAR) CODE : NOT WORKING W/ ERRORS:
error C2668: 'myFunc' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

main program.cpp

```
    #include "otherslib.h"
    #include "mylib.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace myNamespace;

    int main(){

        std::cout << myFunc() << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

mylib.h

```
    #pragma once

    namespace myNamespace{
        int myFunc();
    }
```

mylib.cpp

```
    #include "mylib.h"

    namespace myNamespace{
        int myFunc(){
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

otherslib.h

```
    #pragma once

    int myFunc();
```

otherslib.cpp

```
    #include "otherslib.h"

    int myFunc(){
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Use a namespace. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 4):

You should define your functions in a namespace, and use the namespace when calling them.

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    int myFunc(etc) { ... }
}

int main() {
    cout << myNamespace::myFunc();
}
```

To avoid having to specify your namespace all the time, you could do something like this:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    int myFunc(etc) { ... }

    int main() 
    {
        // Call your own myFunc:
        myFunc();

        // Call their myFunc:
        ::myFunc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid having to call my functions using a namespace? I would rather call the other persons myFunc using a name space since I won't be using their function as often as mine (and I'll only be using their myFunc() inside of my_library.cpp).

Comment: You can `using` your namespace from a particular scope, which will relieve you of specifying it every time. You can `#include` their code into a namespace, but that may cause slightly different semantics than they intended.

Comment: Some reason it's not working - getting errors: 'ambiguous call to overloaded function'

Comment: @Tez what you could do is create an interface to the `otherslib.cpp's myfunc()`. this could be done by creating a wrapper namespace around the `myFunc()` of the `otherlib`